# Case or if on mySQL query

Tags: mysql, join

I have tables like:

**timeline**

```
id data_id   pattern
1     1        add_card
2     1        add_post
3     2        upd_card
4     2        upd_post
```

**card**

```
id    name       parent 
1    cname1          1 
2    cname2          4
3    cname3          5
```

**post**

```
id    name       parent 
1    pname1          8 
2    pname2          9
3    pname3          3
```

i need form result

** result timeline**

```
id data_id    pattern     name      parent
1      1       add_card  cname1        1
2      1       add_post  pname1        8
3      2       upd_card  cname2        4
4      2       upd_post  pname2        9
```

My ideas in only IF or CASE statement

```
SELECT id, data_id, pattern 
      (CASE parent
      WHEN ‘add_card’ THEN (SELECT name.card,parent.card FROM card WHERE data_id.timeline = id.card)
      WHEN ‘add_card’ THEN (SELECT name.post,parent.post FROM post WHERE data_id.timeline = id.post)
       END)
FROM timeline
```

but this is not right syntax, this is just my guess how it would look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to selectively join in the card or post table and `COALESCE` to get the resulting parent/name info in one column:

```
SELECT timeline.id, timeline.data_id, timeline.pattern,
  COALESCE (post.name, card.name) AS name,
  COALESCE (post.parent, card.parent) AS parent
FROM timeline
LEFT OUTER JOIN card ON timeline.data_id = card.id
  AND timeline.pattern IN ('add_card', 'upd_card')
LEFT OUTER JOIN post ON timeline.data_id = post.id
  AND timeline.pattern IN ('add_post', 'upd_post')
```

You can see the result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76d8cb/1/0

The result doesn't match your example result, but your example result appears to be inconsistent with your data, so I think what this does is what you meant. *(Update: I've now edited your example results to be consistent with your example tables.)*

Comment: +1. For solution with JOINs. Good by performance too. Test at [*SQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a568c/3)

Comment: @tgies, and one moment, how to find name on another table in parent http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24f3b/6

Comment: @dev.nikolaz I don't see how that table is supposed to relate to your other tables.

Comment: @tgies we found parent in table card, then this number corresponds in table menu like id. See example on sqlfiddle below

Comment: @tgies menu.id = parent (finded) on 6 line in example

Comment: @dev.nikolaz Just add another join to join `menu.id` on the coalescence of `post.parent_id` and `card.parent_id`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24f3b/14/0

Answer (score -1):

You appear to be checking for the same value and doing 2 different things.

However I think you probably want something like this:-

```
SELECT timeline.id, timeline.data_id, timeline.pattern 
    CASE
        WHEN timeline.pattern = 'add_card' THEN card.name
        WHEN timeline.pattern = 'add_card' THEN post.name
        ELSE NULL
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN timeline.pattern = 'add_card' THEN card.parent
        WHEN timeline.pattern = 'add_card' THEN post.parent
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM timeline
LEFT OUTER JOIN card timeline.data_id = card.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN post timeline.data_id = post.id
```

Comment: You don't need the `CASE`s; you can make timeline.pattern part of the join condition.

Comment: This doesn't work; using `CASE`s in the field list like that doesn't appear to be supported anyway. You are also saying `timeline.parent` where you mean `timeline.pattern`; I'll edit that.

Comment: @tgies -  You can use a case statement in a field list and I have done regularly (or an IF statement, or if you can rely on one value being null which the original questions example SQL doesn't make clear then you can use COALESCE or IFNULL ) although there was a typo with an extra comma.